# I am trying to run rails on Apache, but can't get it into development mode

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I am setting up a development environment for ruby on rails. Using rails 3.0, ubuntu, mysql and apache2 with passenger.

So far so good until  I go to localhost and it tells me:

"Mysql2::Error

Unknown database '[app-name]_production'"

The error occurs because I don't have a production database. Only _development and _test. I have tried using "RailsEnv development" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

```
RailsEnv development
RackEnv development
```

to your httpd.conf file, and restart Apache.

Comment: Thank you! This is the correct answer but SO won't let me accept this for 7 minutes.